# Enable workflow_dispatch in GitHub action without push

Tags: git, github, github-actions

Is there a way to get workflow_dispatch to work (i.e., appear in the "Actions" tab on the web page) without first having a "push" trigger?

I am trying to set up an assignment with automated grading using GitHub actions.

- I want to use `workflow_dispatch` so the tests only run when students specifically launch them (usually through the Actions tab).
- I don't want the students to touch the `.github` files, so I don't want to set up a `push` trigger then ask them to change it later.

The odd thing is that I have been setting up repositories that only have a workflow_dispatch trigger for two years now and haven't had a problem.  Today, I go to set up a new assignment, and I can't get the workflow to appear in the Actions tab.  From what I can tell from other articles, the problem is that a push trigger needs to run first. However, I haven't had to do that before.

The repo only has the one `main` branch, so I don't think this is a "default branch" issue.

This is the repo, if it matters: https://github.com/kurmasz-assignments/cis500-wordle-py.  It's a template repo, and I think repos crated based on the template have the same issue.

There isn't a problem with my workflow below, is there?

```
name: wordle_check
on: workflow_dispatch
jobs:
   run-instructor-tests:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
         - uses: actions/checkout@v3
         - run: curl https://autograder.computing.gvsu.edu/wordle_engine_instructor_test.py --output wordle_engine_instructor_test.py -k
         - run: python3 -m unittest wordle_engine_test.py
         - run: python3 -m unittest wordle_engine_instructor_test.py
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, and if it's on the default branch, it should show up, in my experience. Actionlint doesn't complain, either. Is this the first workflow in the repo?

Comment: It's the only workflow in the repo.  And effectively identical to the workflow used for the project I posted 3 weeks ago.

Comment: I added the repo URL. It's a template repo, and it appears that repos that clone the template have the same issue.

Comment: And the problem was that after the initial commit, it didn't show up in the Actions tab, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: This feels like a bug to me. I can't find anybody reporting the exact issue related to initial commits, only similar ones where it was usually the "not on the default branch" issue, which you've already excluded.

Comment: It started working while I was in a meeting.  So, I agree that it feels like a bug.